# Packaging Windows Application with Wine in deb and rpm format

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows, wine, deb

My Question is can I package a Windows application with WINE in .deb and .rpm file ? Just like TeamViewer and Picasa for Linux.

I don't have the source code of the application available with me, so I cannot compile it using winelib.

Can a installed windows application can be wrapped with all necessary WINE files, so that it runs independently with out installing WINE in a Linux Distro ?

Comment: I think this wonderful question would deserve a bounty - unfortunately, bounties can be given only to answers.

Answer (score 2):

No. The only way to run Windows programs on Linux is with WINE, and therefore you cannot install a Windows application without installing WINE. But you could distribute a .deb or .rpm that lists WINE as a dependency. That would install WINE automatically when your application is installed.